# Android POST JSON OBJECT - How to set $_POST Index

Tags: android

i have a JSONObject which i want to POST to a server.

Here is the Code:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
for(int k = 0; k<len;k++){
    obj.put("nachrichten_ids", params[k]);
}
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("xxxxx");
HttpEntity entity;
StringEntity s = new StringEntity(obj.toString());
s.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
entity = s;
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response;
response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

By doing Log.i("TEST",obj) i get the JSON object:

**{"nachrichten_ids":"[2144,2138]"}**

That data is send to the server. But i cant access it:
**There is no $_POST index.**  (PHP)

How to set a index, so that i can access the json object, **like $_POST['nachrichten_ids']**.
I had to work with that data then e.g with php json_decode()

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting your jSON object into a namevaluepair. The name of the pair you add is the name you should use when reading it on the web. For example here I will get Password by calling $_POST['Password'].

```
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", "My password"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Mail", "My mail"));

    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    BasicHttpResponse response = (BasicHttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

Comment: Hi, you mean i should loop through the JSON object and for each i create an name-value pair ? But then every name value pair has the same index,- e.g "message_id" ... I need only 1 index with multiple values in it

Comment: No, if everything you need is in the obj.toString() you can send that, you don't need to create a new value pair everytime you loop the for-loop (I guess that is the loop you are referencing to?)
So I think something like this should work:
Create a NameValuePair then just 

myvaluepair.add(New BasicNameValuePair("MyjSONobject",obj.toString()));